# catkin error while installing drrobot_jaguar_player

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install drrobot_jaguar_player node when suddenly an error occurs "resource not found: catkin":

```
at-labor1@ubuntu:~$ rosmake drrobot_jaguar4x4_player
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player']                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/at-labor1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130522-155110
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player'] to:
['drrobot_jaguar4x4_player']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> player [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> joy [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> DrRobotMotionSensorDriver [ make ]                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< joy ROS_NOBUILD in package joy
 No Makefile in package joy
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< player [PASS] [ 0.04 seconds ]                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< DrRobotMotionSensorDriver [PASS] [ 0.44 seconds ]      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> drrobot_jaguar4x4_player [ make ]                      
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesrobot_jaguar4x4_player: ... [ 1 Active 18/19 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
      retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
      raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
  ResourceNotFound: catkin
  ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
  ROS path [1]=/home/at-labor1/mystacks
  ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
  ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
  ERROR: catkin
  ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
  ROS path [1]=/home/at-labor1/mystacks
  ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
  ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
  make[3]: *** [../src/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/msg/_IMUInfo.py] Error 3
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/at-labor1/mystacks/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_genmsg_py.dir/all] Error 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_cpp.py", line 44, in <module>
      msg_gen.generate_messages(sys.argv)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 737, in generate_messages
      generate(arg)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 702, in generate
      write_struct(s, spec, cpp_prefix)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 199, in write_struct
      gendeps_dict = roslib.gentools.get_dependencies(spec, spec.package, compute_files=False)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 311, in get_dependencies
      _add_msgs_depends(rospack, spec, deps, package)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 109, in _add_msgs_depends
      _add_msgs_depends(rospack, depspec, deps, package_context)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 75, in _add_msgs_depends
      valid_packages = valid_packages + rospack.get_depends(package_context, implicit=True)
  TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list
  make[3]: *** [../msg_gen/cpp/include/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/IMUInfo.h] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/at-labor1/mystacks/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/at-labor1/mystacks/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/at-labor1/mystacks/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package drrobot_jaguar4x4_player written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/at-labor1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130522-155110/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< drrobot_jaguar4x4_player [FAIL] [ 14.74 seconds ]      
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package drrobot_jaguar4x4_player. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 19 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/at-labor1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130522-155110
```

I've already tried to install catkin via

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-catkin
```

but the same error occurs over and over again. Can someone help me with this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63214/catkin-error-while-installing-drrobot_jaguar_player/) by [julian_ac](https://answers.ros.org/users/4948/julian_ac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-22**:
try removing catkin from the manifest file and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer, Sai!
I could solve the problem by installing catkin manually via git.

---

Originally posted by [julian_ac](https://answers.ros.org/users/4948/julian_ac/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1